# Xamarin multi-dex issue

Tags: xamarin, infragistics

I am using xamarin with infragistics native controls. My android project won't compile because of this

```
trouble writing output: Too many method references: 73153; max is 65536.
        You may try using --multi-dex option.
```

I attempt to enable the mutli dex option, the I get this

```
Error: Error executing task CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries: Could not find file "/Users/..../Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support/multidex/library/libs/android-support-multidex.jar". (Test)
```

How do I fix this in Xamarin? I also can't find android-support-mutlidex.jar to download even if I were to install it...

Help please!

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Android & Xamarin Studio are you using? (I know multi dex support was just added recently)

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Project properties you should see a option to [Enable Multi-Dex](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/#Set_Packaging_Properties).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- enable `ProGuard` first in Android project settings
- if you still have more than 64k Java methods - switch `Multi-Dex` on instead
- if that didn't help, try to disable linker having your `Multi-Dex` enabled

[image]